# React native - Text Input String to HTML Formatter

Tags: javascript, react-native

currently im working on a school project were we have to program an app. We use React-Native as framework.
Im working on a support form Im using [SMTP-Mailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp-mailer) to send a mail from our Mail Server directly.

The user can enter a text that will appear as mail text later but the problem is the formating

For example this shows up in the mail text

`Hello, This is a example text. Greetings`

But it should be

> Hello,
>
> This is a example text.
>
> Greetings

The text needs html formation like `<br>` for a line break.

Is there any libary where a text input converts enters as `<br>` later?
Or any Ideas how to solve it.

Greetings
Landmine

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can break a line using "\n"

```
<Text>Hello, {"\n\n"}This is a example text. {"\n\n"}Greetings</Text>
```

Comment: Yeah but I need a text field that translate an Enter as a line break because its email text that gets written